# Redirect to URL using short names in Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, redirection

My computer runs Windows XP. I have lots of intranet URLs in my company and they are generally big. For example, if I want to access sharepoint site, I have to type

> http://blahblah.com/sites/032/blah.aspx

what I want to do is, just type this in Firefox and it should redirect to the link above.

> blah

How can I do this without using bookmarks/favorites?

Comment: @Seanny123: The extensions listed in your own answer are still valid for Firefox Quantum. So what is the bounty for?

Comment: @harrymc the bounty came before my answer. I legitimately couldn't find anything, but then I had a search epiphany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [**URL Alias** Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/url-alias-8703/). It's easy and simple.

```
1. Type "about:addons" (without quotes) in address bar
2. Go to Extensions > URL Alias > Preferences
3. Each entry is of format "alias URL" (without quotes), one entry per line
4. Special alias '*' (if defined) will act as alias for any non-URL unmatched by other aliases
```

Good for

- Assigning mnemonics to favorite websites.
- "Trapping" http URLs such that they expand to their https service (if provided)

I also tried this [**Alias Links** extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alias-links/hnmffkbofelpmfnimaicmkdhimnaegla?hl=en) in Chrome, although I am a Firefox fan.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed "as not a real question". Clearly, you have given me the answer to what I wanted. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @thandasoru Next time, please at least mention your OS and browser, or explicitly mention that it doesn't matter. You wouldn't want people to write up answers for, let's say, Safari on OS X when you run IE on Windows.

Comment: @slhck There should be a topic on meta regarding these kind of questions and the apparent interest of the OP. I believe that his apparent lack of cooperation got his question labelled as above. Coming from a different time zone from most users here, sometimes I post a question wait until everybody wakes up, I get a good night's sleep, and next thing you know, my questions got answered after 7 hours, and I wasn't able to provide feedback while the topic was 'hot'.

Comment: @WikiWitz It should be somewhat self explanatory that one should be following up on their questions for at least one hour or so after posting them. Most comments for clarification arrive within that time. It's often seen as rude to post a question, asking for help, and not cooperating in the sense of sticking around and responding to those who try to help.

Comment: @slhck Yea, I realized that a bit late. While typing the question, in my mind, I was saying Firefox, but missed it out while typing :-D.. And as the Wikiwitz pointed out, I didn't realize it soon. I will be more careful next time. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 5):

Now that the `URL Alias` add-on is no longer maintained, a number of alternative extensions exist.

### [WeAlias](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wealias/)

Allow you to either:

1. Hit a keyboard shortcut before entering an alias
2. Prepend `a` to your alias in the navigation bar
3. Open a new tab to enter the alias you desire

### [uAlias](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ualias/)

Make you prepend `u` to your alias in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a "power user", you may appreciate [pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/). It provides support for 'QuickMarks', allowing you to use keyboard navigation (to "type this in Firefox"), to quickly move to a site. It has a host of other features as well, enabling you to use the browser much more efficiently (although it comes with a bit of a learning curve).